# columns to data matrix awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm looking for an `awk` solution to get from this table (with x number of names in column 1, and different lengths of column 2 which is ";" separated):

dataframe.txt:

```
name1 1;2;4;8
name2 4;5;7
name3 8
name4 11;12
namex 20;21
```

to this matrix with present `1` and non present `0`:

matrix.txt:

```
        1 2 4 5 7 8 11 12 20 21
name1   1 1 1 0 0 1 0  0  0  0 
name2   0 0 1 1 1 0 0  0  0  0
name3   0 0 0 0 0 1 0  0  0  0
name4   0 0 0 0 0 0 1  1  0  0
namex   0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  1  1
```

Comment: `previous examples` please click [edit] and add that code/question-link to the question... it'd also help if you add what changes you attempted.. that'd show your research efforts.. regarding expected output shown, on what basis column is added? there is no `1` in column under `3`.. is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 11 12 20 21` known beforehand?

Answer (score 2):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
         h = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 11 12 20 21";
         len = split(h, head);
         print "\t\t" h
     }
     {
         printf "%s\t", $1;
         for (i = 1; i <= len; i++)
             printf "%s%d", (i == 1? "" : OFS), ($2 ~ "\\<" head[i] "\\>");
         print "" 
     }' file
```

- `h = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 11 12 20 21"` - *header* line
- `len = split(h, head)` - split `h` line into array `head` where indices are ordered positions starting from `1` and values are crucial values obtained via splitting; `len` contains an array size
- `print "\t\t" h` - print the *header* line with leading tab characters
- `printf "%s\t", $1;` - print the 1st field `$1`
- `for (i = 1; i <= len; i++)` - iterate through `head` items

  - `$2 ~ "\\<" head[i] "\\>"` - check if the 2nd field `$2` contains currently accessed item `head[i]`

---

The output:

```
        1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 11 12 20 21
name1   1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
name2   0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
name3   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
name4   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
namex   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: thanks for the code and the comments! Unfortunately I get a matrix with only 0's.
I tried changing `printf "%s%d", (i == 1? "" : OFS )` this command to get the 1's but can't get it to work :/

Comment: @newAWKer, it works fine. What's your `awk --version`?

Comment: awk version 20070501

Comment: @newAWKer, try to change `($2 ~ "\\<" head[i] "\\>")` to `($2 ~ "\\<" head[i] "\\>" ? 1:0)`

Comment: I changed it to ($2 ~ head[i] ? 1:0) and then it worked! thanks a lot!!

Comment: but with ($2 ~ head[i]) it takes the 11 and 12 apart and matches it to 1 and 2

Comment: what can I replace the "\\<" and "\\>" with in the future?

Comment: Note that header is not always fixed digits or length, also you can do `for(i in head)` for `for (i = 1; i <= len; i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` approach which generate header first by itself and then fill the matrix with **1** for each key in array `head` exist in current input line otherwise with **0** if doesn't exist.

We used `grep` to fetch only `-o` numbers which matches the empty string at the left edge of a number `\b` (same as `\<` we used in `awk` for both left&right sides).

```
awk 'NR==FNR { !head[$1]++; next } 
    { printf $1; for (x in head) { printf (x?FS:"") ($0 ~ "\\<" x "\\>") }; print ""
}' <(grep -o '\b[0-9]\+' infile) infile
```

The output is:

```
name1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
name2 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
name3 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
name4 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
namex 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

---

You could generate the header and insert in first line in input file, then the `awk` would be easy as:

```
awk 'NR==1{ split($0, head); next }
    { printf $1; for (x in head){ printf (x?FS:"") ($2 ~ "\\<" head[x] "\\>" ) }; 
print "" }' infile
```